# I want to get p tag's text and other tag's text inside the p tag in order by bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I selected a content from soup, there are three types.

1. `<p>first</p>`
2. `<p><span>first</span></p>`
3. `<p>first<span>second</span>third</p>`

And I want to get text from the last in order like "first", "second", "third".
First, I use '.text' and the last one returned "firstsecondthird". But I want to get text one by one.
Is there a way?

I edited question so you can get more detail information.

```py
contents_list = soup.select('blabla')

# contents_list =
# ['<p>first</p>',
# '<p><span>first</span></p>',
# '<p>first<span>second</span>third</p>']

for content in contents_list:
  print(content.text)

# I want to get
# first
# first
# first, second, third
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you have already tried

Comment: @MendelG I edit my question. I'm new to stack overflow, so I'm not familiar with it. Sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tags separated with a space, you can use the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method with adding a space as the `separator` argument. `.get_text(separator=" ")`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<p>first</p>
<p><span>first</span></p>
<p>first<span>second</span>third</p>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("p"):
    print(tag.get_text(separator=" "))
```

Output:

```
first
first
first second third
```